# Is there a use case of keeping 2 chains?

Tags: go-ethereum, network

I know that Ethereum was forked 2 chains due to DAO hacking. so Ethereum Classic was borned at that time. 2 chains are distinguishable by different chain id.

I had a strange idea, a malicious miner can keep two chains(for example ETH, ETC). Think of this way, I have a two machine and one(A) is running on ETH network, another(B) is running on ETC. connection can be established between A and B if I want. A node can delivery the block to B node when it get a propagated block, also vice versa. the benefit which can be given by doing this is that I can mine two types(ETH,ETC) block to earn reward.

1. Do you think this is illegal?
2. Do you think this has practicality to earn reward by keeping two chains?

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two chains have the same technical origin but that doesn't mean that they would be equal otherwise. I recommend you to read a bit more about how mining works.

A block in Eth is not a valid block in Etc (after the fork). A block contains the has value of the previous block and all the blocks started to have different contents after the fork which means also different hash values. So if you try to insert a block from one chain to the other it would get discarded by the network as it points to a wrong previous block's hash value.

Furthermore there is no such thing as "illegal" mining unless your country ha some strange specific laws about it. Whatever you can do is allowed to do. You can execute the scheme you proposed but it wouldn't give you any benefits. The network is designed to handle all abuse itself - there is no centralized authority to determine whether someone is acting in a wrong way.